# Error de autenticación de usuario con passport, express-session y bcrypt

Tags: nodejs, passport, express-session, bcryptjs

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación usando Node.js, Express, MySQL y Angular. Estoy encontrando un error de autenticación con el usuario, y creo que el problema radica en la función Passport.deserializeUser() ya que no devuelve la ID en la consola.

Aquí está el código:

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const morgan = require('morgan');
const cors = require('cors');

const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');
const passport = require('passport');
const session = require('express-session');
const LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;

const flash = require('connect-flash');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;


// Configuración de la sesión
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(
  session({
    secret: 'secret_key',
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: true
  })
);

    // Configuración de Passport
    app.use(passport.initialize());
    app.use(passport.session());

    passport.use(new LocalStrategy({ usernameField: 'email', passwordField: 'password' }, (email, password, done) => {
      connection.query('SELECT * FROM encargado WHERE email = ?', [email], (err, rows) => {
        if (err) {
          console.error(err);
          return done(null, false, { message: 'Error interno del servidor' });
        }

        if (!rows.length) {
          return done(null, false, { message: 'Email o contraseña incorrectos' });
        }

        const user = rows[0];
        bcrypt.compare(password, user.contrasenia, (err, result) => {
          if (err) {
            console.error(err);
            return done(null, false, { message: 'Error interno del servidor' });
          }

          console.log('Filas de la consulta:', user.id_encargado);
          console.log('Comparación de contraseñas:', result);

          if (result) {
            return done(null, user); // Llama a done con el objeto user completo
          } else {
            return done(null, false, { message: 'Email o contraseña incorrectos' });
          }
        });
      });
    }));



passport.serializeUser((user, done) => {
  console.log('Serializando usuario:', user);
  done(null, user.id_encargado);
});

passport.deserializeUser((user, done) => {
  console.log('Deserializando usuario:', user.id_encargado);
  connection.query('SELECT * FROM encargado WHERE id_encargado = ?', [user.id_encargado], (err, rows) => {
    if (err) {
      console.error(err);
      return done(err);
    }

    if (rows.length === 0) {
      console.log('Usuario no encontrado');
      return done(null, false);
    }

    const deserializedUser = rows[0];
    console.log('Usuario deserializado:', deserializedUser);
    done(null, deserializedUser);
  });
});


// Middleware para verificar la autenticación del encargado
function ensureAuthenticated(req, res, next) {
  if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
    console.log('Usuario autenticado:', req.user.id_encargado);
    return next();
  }
  
  console.log('Usuario no autenticado');
  return res.status(401).json({ error: 'No autorizado' });
}




//settings
app.set('port', port);

//middlewares
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(morgan('dev'));
app.use(cors({ credentials: true }));


//rutes
app.use('/bovino', require('./rutes/bovino'));






// Método para obtener el perfil del encargado
app.get('/profile', ensureAuthenticated, (req, res) => {
  const query = `
  SELECT id_encargado, nombre, apellido, email, finca, telefono, contrasenia
  FROM encargado
  WHERE id_encargado = ?
  `;

  connection.query(query, [req.user.id_encargado], (err, encargadoRows) => {
    if (err) {
      console.error(err);
      return res.status(500).json({ error: 'Error interno del servidor' });
    }

    if (encargadoRows.length === 0) {
      return res.status(404).json({ error: 'Encargado no encontrado' });
    }

    const encargado = encargadoRows[0];

    connection.query('SELECT * FROM res WHERE id_encargado = ?', [req.user.id_encargado], (err, resRows) => {
      if (err) {
        console.error(err);
        return res.status(500).json({ error: 'Error interno del servidor' });
      }

      encargado.res = resRows;
      res.json({ encargado });
    });
  });
});





//login
app.post('/login', (req, res, next) => {
  passport.authenticate('local', (err, user, info) => {
    if (err) {
      console.error(err);
      return res.status(500).json({ error: 'Error interno del servidor' });
    }
    
    if (!user) {
      return res.status(401).json({ error: 'Email o contraseña incorrectos' });
    }

    req.logIn(user, (err) => {
      if (err) {
        console.error(err);
        return res.status(500).json({ error: 'Error interno del servidor' });
      }
    
      return res.status(200).json({ message: 'Inicio de sesión exitoso' });
    });
  })(req, res, next);
});

app.get('/logout', (req, res) => {
  req.logout(() => {
    res.json({ message: 'Cierre de sesión exitoso' });
  });
});
//Singup
app.post('/signup', (req, res) => {
  const { nombre, apellido, finca, email, password, telefono } = req.body;

  bcrypt.hash(password, 10, (err, hashedPassword) => {
    if (err) {
      console.error(err);
      return res.status(500).json({ error: 'Error interno del servidor' });
    }

    const newUser = {
      nombre: nombre,
      apellido: apellido,
      finca: finca,
      email: email,
      contrasenia: hashedPassword,
      telefono: telefono
    };

    connection.query('INSERT INTO encargado SET ?', newUser, (err) => {
      if (err) {
        console.error(err);
        return res.status(500).json({ error: 'Error interno del servidor' });
      }

      res.json({ message: 'Registro exitoso' });
    });
  });
});




//static files
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

//start the server
app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server listening on port ${port}`);
});
```

Consola:

OPTIONS /login 204 0.134 ms - 0

Filas de la consulta: 25

Comparación de contraseñas: true

Serializando usuario: {
id_encargado: 25,
nombre: 'Lowewe',
apellido: 'Mg',
finca: 'Vanhalla',
email: 'rsee@gmail.com',
contrasenia: '$2b$10$MGNp2.V5FUJGmbRdQdJA.esP1THDaHZXlkdQ9R7odRD1orctQH.M2',
telefono: '3232353555'
}

POST /login 200 61.716 ms - 39

Usuario no autenticado

GET /profile 401 4.549 ms - 25

***Sospecho que el problema radica en la función pasaporte. deserializeUser() ya que no devuelve la identificación como se esperaba. Agradecería cualquier idea o sugerencia para resolver este problema. ¡Gracias!

---

Comment: use the english site on StackOverflow, the questions on this site must be entirely in Spanish